# Subprocess adding non-recognized option

Tags: python, subprocess

Right so the jar I am opening has a gui which normally would be closed with the following batch code

> java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar Spigot-1.16.4.jar --nogui

The issue is if i try adding --nogui to subprocess like this

> subprocess.Popen(['java', '-Xmx1024M', '-Xms1024M', '-jar','--nogui', f'{self.fileSelected}'+f'/{jarFile}'], cwd = self.fileSelected)

I end up getting unrecognized option: --nogui

How can I implement --nogui to the subprocess code?

Comment: Put `--nogui` after the jarfile name in the arguments list.

Comment: Voting to close as caused-by-typo (though changing the ordering unnecessarily might be more properly described as a "thinko" -- but point being, your two commands are not like each other: One puts the filename of the jar _before_ `--nogui`, the other puts it after).

Comment: ...the difference is that if you put `--nogui` _after_ the jar name it's treated as an argument _to your Java program_, but if you put it first, it's treated as an argument _to Java itself_.